# SignalR 2.2 clients not receiving any messages

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

I have a self-hosted SignalR application running in the context of a console app. I'm connecting to the hubs within it through the use of a wrapper class to prevent me from having to reference the SignalR.Core assemblies from my ASP.NET project. So it's another C# class from within my application that's responsible for broadcasting messages to connected clients.

I'm able to call the `PlanHub` methods (`Register` and `Unregister`) directly from Javascript, those breakpoints get hit. However, when I call client methods from a class outside of the Hub (even if I use `Clients.All` to eliminate problems with the Group registration), the clients never get the message. What am I doing wrong?

**When running this code, I can verify that the `Clients.All.updateStatus(planId, message);` code is being hit successfully, but nothing is logged to the console on the client.**

Here's the relevant code:

**PlanHub.cs**

```
public class PlanHub : Hub
{
    private const string GroupPrefix = "PlanGroup_";

    public void Register(int companyId)
    {
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, $"{GroupPrefix}{companyId}");
    }

    public void Unregister(int companyId)
    {
        Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, $"{GroupPrefix}{companyId}");
    }
}
```

**PlanPublisher.cs**

```
public class PlanPublisher
{
    private readonly static Lazy<PlanPublisher> _instance = new Lazy<PlanPublisher>(() => 
        new PlanPublisher(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PlanHub>().Clients));
    private IHubConnectionContext<dynamic> Clients { get; set; }

    private PlanPublisher(IHubConnectionContext<dynamic> clients)
    {
        Clients = clients;
    }

    public static PlanPublisher Instance => _instance.Value;

    public void UpdateStatus(int planId, string message)
    {
        //This code gets hit and no exceptions are thrown, but the clients
        //never receive the message. Using Clients.All instead of my 
        //Groups for testing -- still doesn't work
        Clients.All.updateStatus(planId, message);
    }
}
```

**Calling code (from within another C# class)**

```
PlanPublisher.Instance.UpdateStatus(plan.Id, $"Publishing started for {plan.Name}...");
```

**Javascript**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";

        var planMessagePublisher = $.connection.planHub;

        planMessagePublisher.client.updateStatus = function (planId, message) {
            console.log('Status: ' + planId + ' - ' + message);
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
            //This works! My PlanHub.Register method gets called successfully
            planMessagePublisher.server.register(@Model.CompanyId);

            // New connection ID is successfully sent to console
            console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**JS Console Debugger Output**

```
jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js?v=8588299:8 [06:23:19 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)] SignalR: Auto detected cross domain url.
jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js?v=8588299:8 [06:23:19 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'planhub'.
jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js?v=8588299:8 [06:23:19 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with 'http://localhost:8080/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22planhub%22%7D%5D'.
jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js?v=8588299:8 [06:23:19 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport starting.
jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js?v=8588299:8 [06:23:19 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)] SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://localhost:8080/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAA5D8YUVyzBEG4tTlTaGn0MgAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAABDjF1MaCTzZI0XTM8gC29xAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAKrk0jv%2FKF4YFzDvNwmSR8IoAAAAacm1d1r7dJpjOtVtCFIFRpugkubyZm1e5Z8OtOFtnhZyEBO1SO4lqhQAAABiG7hBydTiypPh8k2ZYz20ropNxw%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22planhub%22%7D%5D&tid=6'.
jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js?v=8588299:8 [06:23:19 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)] SignalR: Websocket opened.
jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js?v=8588299:8 [06:23:19 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport connected. Initiating start request.
jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js?v=8588299:8 [06:23:19 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js?v=8588299:8 [06:23:19 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000
jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js?v=8588299:8 [06:23:19 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)] SignalR: Invoking planhub.Register
jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js?v=8588299:8 [06:23:19 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)] SignalR: Invoked planhub.Register
```

It registers successfully, but never receives any data. The `Clients.All.updateStatus(planId, message);` breakpoint was hit multiple times but the console never received any additional logging data.

**EDIT:** It was suggested that I look into whether or not a custom dependency resolver is in play. The code posted here lives in its own project with very little else, other than what you see here. The code that calls `PlanPublisher.UpdateStatus()` DOES have a custom dependency resolver, but that shouldn't matter since it's isolated in its own assembly. `PlanPublisher.cs` and `PlanHub.cs` are contained in a very simple project that just has references to SignalR.Core and SignalR.SelfHost.

Comment: You need to provide minimal example which reproduces your issue. I just tried to run with the exact code your provided on both server and client side, and it went fine without any problems.

Comment: @Scott, did you manage to resolve it somehow? Cause I am facing very same issue. The funny part-if I try to publish for the group, it works, but not for All. On the other hand, when I create a separate project just to try this functionality, everything works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to simplify your example (using SignalR 2.2.0)

Hub class:

```
public class PlanHub : Hub
{
    private const string GroupPrefix = "PlanGroup_";

    // hubcontext
    private static IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext <PlanHub> ();

    public void Register(int companyId)
    {
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, $"{GroupPrefix}{companyId}");
    }

    public void Unregister(int companyId)
    {
        Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, $"{GroupPrefix}{companyId}");
    }

    // static method using hub context
    public static void Static_UpdateStatus(int planId, string message)
    {
        hubContext.Clients.All.updateStatus(planId, message);
    }
}
```

Since I don't really have a backend and I don't know how you are going to do that, I just set up a timer to call the method from C# every 10 seconds.

Calling and dummy timer:

```
    public void startTimer()
    {
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(ExecuteTimerJob);
        timer.Interval = 10000; // 10 sec
        timer.Start();
    }

    public static void ExecuteTimerJob(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // this is the call from C#
        PlanHub.Static_UpdateStatus(123, "some message");
    }
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var planHub = $.connection.planHub;
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
         console.debug('Connected to PlanHub...');
    })
    planHub.client.updateStatus = function (planId, message) {
        console.log("planId: " + planId);
        console.log("message: " + message);
    } 
});
```

Result in browser console:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public void UpdateStatus(int planId, string message)
{
    var clients = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PlanHub>().Clients;
    clients.All.updateStatus(planId, message);
}
```

I think the problem is that *PlanPublisher* is initialized before the hub context (and *Clients*) is created.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just tried it, same behavior though.

Comment: Can you post the .js console debugging? `$.connection.hub.logging = true;`